# October CMS - AJAX Form submit from 1 component to another

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-widgets

I am making a website in October CMS.

i created 1 components lets say Component_1 & Component_2

Now, i want to post data from Component_1 to Component_2 through form [via AJAX data-attributes APi]

So, in my component_1 i have a Form:

```
<form method="POST" data-request="Component_2::onSubmit" data-request-flash>
```

and in Component_2 i have method onSubmit(){ //Nothing Here }

When i submit form i get an error:

```
AJAX handler 'Component_2::onSubmit' was not found.
```

Then i have a same function in Component_1::onSubmit & when i submit this form to the Component_1::onSubmit i get no errors.

So, Could you suggest me a way to submit the form through AJAX from component_1 to component_2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm it should work, **make sure you are using `component alias` names instead of using its `class name`**,

> just to inform that we are `not passing data from one component to another` its just a regular `ajax request` and we send data from `browser to component`

if I declare `class class componentOne { ... etc` we will not use this one.

then when `we include` it inside page there will be `alias name` you need to use that `alias name` to request ajax.

[image]

### Update (using ajax handler of different page)

we need to use `ajax JavaScript API` it will give us more flexiblity

you can use this code

```
<!-- current page is `test` 
we are requesting ajax request on anohter `testing` page which is having 
compoTwo component and having `onAjaxReq` ajax handler -->
<button onClick="requestAnotherPage(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >
    My button
</button>

<script>
function requestAnotherPage(th) {
    $(th).request('compoTwo::onAjaxReq', {
        url: "{{ 'testing'|page }}", // <- this option
        // url: "http://timeloger.test/testing", 
        flash: 1,
        data: { id: 2, name: 'hardik'},     
        handleFlashMessage: function(message, type) {
            $.oc.flashMsg({ text: message, class: type })
        },
        success: function(data) { console.log('success'); this.success(data); }
    });
}
</script>
```

you need to take care url of another page

> `{{ 'testing'|page }}` will generate that page's url `http://timeloger.test/testing` you need to pass `page File Name` as parameter there `{{ 'page-name'|page }}` -> it will generate proper url

now `ajax api` can request to `another given page url` and `fetch data` from it.

Comment: Hi Hardik, thanks for having look, i am using the same alias but still no success, in my case i have component 1 on homepage and component 2 on another page... basically on homepage i have a search component and i am trying to post data to a component defined on another page as i need the search parameters in this 2nd component which is defined on another page.

Comment: hmmm, it seems `ajax-framework` is using `url: window.location.href,` so it will always try to `fire ajax` on same url so it will `pick same page rather then other page` so, it seems its `not possible to call different page's ajax-hander from current page` - still i will try to find some work-around and post it